# libgnome-window-settings-dev - package not found

Tags: 12.04, libraries

I use UBuntu 12.04 LTS - I have to install all dependencies listed here: [link](http://wiki.compiz.org/C++Compiling) Apt can't install **libgnome-window-settings-dev**

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome-window-settings-dev
package not found.
```

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `libgnome-window-settings-dev` does not exist for Ubuntu 12.04, the only installation candidate can be found for Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid).

Go through this link of [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgnome-window-settings-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) to see the details.